# how to learn from each fold in the k-fold cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

When performing k-fold cross-validation, for every fold, we have a different validation set and a slightly changed learning set. Say that you progress from the first fold to the second fold. How is what υοu learned from the first fold being inherited in the second fold iteration? Currently, it seems as you only calculate the accuracy and the model learned is discarded and never retained.

What am I missing? If such a model is retained? How is it retained and does the method differ for DQN from KNN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**K-fold cross-validation** does not retrain models in each iteration. Instead, it **trains and evaluates K different *independent*** (could be parallelized) **models** with different folds of the dataset, but **with the same hyper-parameters**. This is not to get a more accurate model, but to get a more accurate (statistically speaking) validation by computing the aggregated validation score (i.e.: you can estimate the mean and stddev of the accuracy of the model).

You can then just keep one of those models and use the aggregated estimation for its metrics (instead of using the one computed in the specific fold for that model), or train (from scratch) a new model with the complete dataset. In this last case, your best estimation for the model metrics is still the previous aggregated metrics, but a new unused test set could be used to estimate a new metric. So, why would you do that? Well, that is because you normally use cross-validation combined with hyper-parameters tuning. So, every time you tune your hyperparameters, you just check the aggregated metric estimation with cross-validation. But, when you finish tuning your model, you compute the final metrics with the unseen test set.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a case where you want to find a regression model for some data. You have various choices on how many terms your model will use. More terms might mean better accuracy but it also means risk of overfitting. To select the right model, set about training them with some `train data` and testing them against some `test data` which are usually mutually exclusive.

Now to get more precise approximations on how accurate your model is, you can use k-fold cross-validation which allows you to use as many as `k` `test datasets`. Note that you're using k-fold to evaluate *how good your model is, given some data*, not to train it. In fact k-fold is barely used when the cost of training is high (e.g. deep neural networks) or your dataset is big enough to ensure a well enough approximation of your models accuracy.

So to answer your last question: no the model is not necessarily retained. you can re-train it with all the data you have once you're ready for real-life practice.